# Create a transparent div over opaque div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div :

- The main div is color green => DIV1
- Inside the main I have opaque red div => DIV2
- Inside the red div, I have a    final div => DIV3

I would like the final div (DIV3) to be completely transparent, so that it shown the green one (DIV1), like a "hole" in the red div (DIV2).

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div2 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, the final div (DIV3) would "cancel" completely the red parent div (DIV2) opacity.

Is it possible ?

**EDIT 1** : Something like this :

[image]

**EDIT 2 :**

Something like this would work, but I need to set the width  manually via js at each resize in order to cover the screen correctly :

```
position: absolute;
border: solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
border-top-width: 50px;
border-bottom-width: 50px;
border-left-width: 50px;
border-right-width: 50px;
```

Comment: Look into masking using a canvas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395369/javascript-canvas-intersecting-circle-holes-in-rectangle-or-how-to-merge-multi

Comment: Can you post an image of your requirement?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241571/make-div-transparent-through-parent-div/50242118#50242118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mix-blend-mode` property. This property is used to specify the blend mode for blending an element with its backdrop.

A backdrop is the content behind the element—known as the source element—and is what the element is composited with. The destination element is the element that lies behind the source element, and which the source overlaps with. The backdrop is the area where the color blending is done between the source and the destination.

Here is a solution snippet for your question.

```css
.destination {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 background: blue;  /*Change the background color to change the color inside the BOX*/
}

.backdrop {
 position: relative;
 left: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 background-color: white;
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.source {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="destination">
 <div class="backdrop">
  <div class="source">BOX</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about `mix-blend-mode` [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/mix-blend-mode/).

Comment: Thanks for that, I have found another solution in the meantime, but I guess that could have worked.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simple workaround. Check if it works for your purposes:

```css
div {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1200/800);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

div > div {
  background: transparent;
  border: 60px solid rgba(200, 0, 0, .9);
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have found another solution in the meantime, but I guess that could have worked.